# How to access response code and body by calling a method returning http.Response?

Tags: flutter, dart, http

I use the following class (a separate dart file) to provide API services:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class Services {
  static Future<http.Response> login(String username, String password) async {
    var url = "https://10.0.2.2:5001/api/Login/LoginSystem";
    Map data = {"Username": username, "Password": password};
    var body = json.encode(data);
    var response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url),
        headers: {
          "content-type": "application/json",
          "accept": "application/json"
        },
        body: body);

    print(response.statusCode);
    print(response.body);
    return response;
  }
}
```

And I use the following code to call the service function:

```
onPressed: () {
    var response = Services.login("fa2020", "123");
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    showDialog<String>(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) =>
    const AlertDialog(
        title: Text("ALert"),
        content: Text(response.body),
        ));
    }
}
```

My problem is that I cannot access the `response.statusCode` and `response.body` in the last code. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `async-await` in `onPressed` callback as `Service.login` executes in async manner.

```dart
onPressed: () async {
  var response = await Services.login("fa2020", "123");
  // ...
},
```